# What is explanation for this FOR-IF loop?

Tags: c++

I am writing a code for GCD in C++ but I am encountering a mysterious error that I can't seem to think of its probable reason.

In the below program if both the numbers are equal to `i` ... it will break and return the value of `i`.

But it doesn't seems to work **because it outputs the result as `1`**.

```
int gcd2(int a, int b) {
    int i,hcf=0;
    if (b > a) {
        a = a + b;
        b = a - b;
        a = a - b;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= b; ++i) {
        if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return i; 
}
```

But when I add a variable **HCF** in the same code :

```
int gcd2(int a, int b) {
    int i,hcf=0;
    if (b > a) {
        a = a + b;
        b = a - b;
        a = a - b;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= b; ++i) {
        if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
            hcf = i;
        }
    }
    return hcf;
}
```

It works. Why is that? Can anyone clarify?

Comment: _In the below program if both the numbers are equal to `i` ... it will break and return the value of `i`._ This is not what the code is doing. The expression `a % i == 0` checks whether the remainder when `a` is divided by `i` equals 0, that is, whether `a` is _divisible_ by `i`. This won't cause what you're encountering, but it is an important distinction

Comment: do you know a number that is not divisible by `1` ? The second version is very different because it has no `break`

Comment: details do matter. In the second code you not only added a variable `hfc`. You changed something else also

Comment: Explanation of the first code:  the for begin with i =1 and in this case (a%1 ==0 && b%1 ==0) so that it "Break" and you get out of the for loop with i=1

Comment: @JaziriRami code in comments is not readable and answers better go to answers

Comment: I am very sorry for misunderstanding .... the first code was written by me and second i got it from somewhere else.

Comment: Are you writing it for learning purposes or because you need the function? You have [std::gcd](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) if you just need one that works.

Comment: Off-topic, but this is an extremely inefficient algorithm. Euclid found a better one 2300 years ago.

Comment: @idclev463035818 But i thought the '++i'  means it will increment first (so i becomes 2) and then executes it

Comment: That part of the `for` loops executes after the loop body, before the next loop test is performed.

Comment: frankly, then you need to reread the chapter about for loops in your c++ book. The increment is done after the body of the loop

Comment: @idclev463035818 iam very sorry for bothering iam new to programming.

Comment: no worries. The real issue here is that you need to realize that the two loops do something very different as explained in the answers, the thing about starting at `1` or `2` is a minor one imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `hfc` is not the cause for the difference you notice. If we keep the difference but introduce a `hfc` in both versions we have:

```
int hfc = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= b; ++i) {
    if (some_condition(i)) {
        hfc = i;
        break;                  // breaks out of the loop
    }
}
return hfc;
```

vs

```
int hfc = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= b; ++i) {
    if (some_condition(i)) {
        hfc = i;                 // no break !!!
    }
}
return hfc;
```

The first returns the first value of `i` for which `some_condition(i)` is `true`. The second version returns the last value of `i` for which `some_condition(i)` is `true`. This and the fact that any number is divisible by `1` explains the different results you get.

Answer (score 1):

The simple difference between your two samples is whether the loop goes through the whole interval and whether the first or last match is returned.

Using `break` makes it to stop when the *first* number fulfilling the condition is found. As commenters note, 1 is the divider of all numbers, so you should rather have started with `i = 2`. However, this variant still won’t find the *greatest* common divisor in all cases.

On the other hand, the variable assignment can be called multiple times, so your second sample returns the *last*, i.e. greatest number found which is most likely your desired result.